# How to set tag to UIImageview Image is equal to Array Index for each Image in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uiimageview

i am newbie in iOS Development. i want to set tag an imageview image is equal to its value in my Array index like as my Array Contain 50 image link and i set a imageview to image code like as

```
for(int index=0; index < [self.imagesa count]; index++)
{
    NSDictionary *dict=[self.imagesa objectAtIndex:index];
    NSString *image=[dict valueForKey:@"link"];
    smallImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    pageLabel=[[UILabel alloc]init];
    smallImage.tag=index;
    smallImage.bounds = CGRectMake(10, 10, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.width);
    smallImage.frame = CGRectMake(5+xOffset, 0, 50, 50);
    [smallImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:image] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]];
    [self.imageArray insertObject:smallImage atIndex:index];
    CGSize scrollViewSize=CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width*[self.imageArray count], self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:scrollViewSize];
    CALayer *borderLayer = [CALayer layer];
    CGRect borderFrame = CGRectMake(10, 10, (smallImage.frame.size.width), (smallImage.frame.size.height));
    [borderLayer setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];
    [borderLayer setFrame:borderFrame];
    [borderLayer setCornerRadius:kCornerRadius];
    [borderLayer setBorderWidth:kBoarderWidth];
    [borderLayer setBorderColor:[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];
    [smallImage.layer addSublayer:borderLayer];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:smallImage];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:pageLabel];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:[self.imageArray objectAtIndex:index]];
    xOffset += 60;
}
```

Here i want like as if i select 5th image then it tag is also Five how it possible?here i set imageview.tag=index but it is always Returen as my Array Count Value. PLease give me Solution FOr Each imagetag is Equal to its Index in Array.

thnx in advance.

Comment: Have you initialised self.imageArray?

Comment: Yes @Gismay i initialised it.it is always set last index of my Array index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have improved your code and added a `UIButton` as a click area:

```
self.imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int index=0; index < [self.imagesa count]; index++){
    NSDictionary *dict=[self.imagesa objectAtIndex:index];
    NSString *imageString = [dict valueForKey:@"link"];

    UIImageView *smallImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    smallImage.bounds = CGRectMake(10, 10, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.width);
    smallImage.frame = CGRectMake(5+(index*60), 0, 50, 50);
    [smallImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageString] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]];
    smallImage.layer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
    smallImage.layer.cornerRadius = kCornerRadius;
    smallImage.layer.borderWidth = kBoarderWidth;
    smallImage.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
    [self.imageArray addObject:smallImage];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:smallImage];

    UIButton *clickArea = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    clickArea.frame = smallImage.frame;
    clickArea.tag = index;
    [clickArea addTarget:self action:@selector(clickAreaClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:clickArea];
}

// Doesn't need to be in for-loop
CGSize scrollViewSize=CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width*[self.imageArray count], self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
[self.scrollView setContentSize:scrollViewSize];
```

And to get the tag from the `UIButton` click:

```
- (void)clickAreaClicked:(UIButton*)sender
{
    NSLog(@"sender tag: %i", sender.tag );
}
```

I have just tested it and it works. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add button to scrollview and set tag to it..

```
for(int index=0; index < [self.imagesa count]; index++)
{
    NSDictionary *dict=[self.imagesa objectAtIndex:index];
    NSString *image=[dict valueForKey:@"link"];
    smallImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    imageButton =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    pageLabel=[[UILabel alloc]init];
    smallImage.tag=index;
    smallImage.bounds = CGRectMake(10, 10, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.width);
    smallImage.frame = CGRectMake(5+xOffset, 0, 50, 50);
    imageButton.frame=CGRectMake(5+xOffset, 0, 50, 50);
    imageButton.tag=index;
    [imageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(imageClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [smallImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:image] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]];
    [self.imageArray insertObject:smallImage atIndex:index];
    CGSize scrollViewSize=CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width*[self.imageArray count], self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:scrollViewSize];
    CALayer *borderLayer = [CALayer layer];
    CGRect borderFrame = CGRectMake(10, 10, (smallImage.frame.size.width), (smallImage.frame.size.height));
    [borderLayer setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];
    [borderLayer setFrame:borderFrame];
    [borderLayer setCornerRadius:kCornerRadius];
    [borderLayer setBorderWidth:kBoarderWidth];
    [borderLayer setBorderColor:[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];
    [smallImage.layer addSublayer:borderLayer];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:smallImage];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:imageButton];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:pageLabel];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:[self.imageArray objectAtIndex:index]];
    xOffset += 60;
}
```

//(OR)

```
for(int index=0; index < [self.imagesa count]; index++)
{
    NSDictionary *dict=[self.imagesa objectAtIndex:index];
    NSString *image=[dict valueForKey:@"link"];
    smallImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    pageLabel=[[UILabel alloc]init];
    smallImage.tag=index;
    smallImage.bounds = CGRectMake(10, 10, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.width);
    smallImage.frame = CGRectMake(5+xOffset, 0, 50, 50);
    [smallImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:image] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer =
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    [tapRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];

        [smallImage addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
    [self.imageArray insertObject:smallImage atIndex:index];
    CGSize scrollViewSize=CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width*[self.imageArray count], self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:scrollViewSize];
    CALayer *borderLayer = [CALayer layer];
    CGRect borderFrame = CGRectMake(10, 10, (smallImage.frame.size.width), (smallImage.frame.size.height));
    [borderLayer setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];
    [borderLayer setFrame:borderFrame];
    [borderLayer setCornerRadius:kCornerRadius];
    [borderLayer setBorderWidth:kBoarderWidth];
    [borderLayer setBorderColor:[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];
    [smallImage.layer addSublayer:borderLayer];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:smallImage];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:pageLabel];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:[self.imageArray objectAtIndex:index]];
    xOffset += 60;
}

- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    UIImageView *currentimage = (UIImageView *)[recognizer view];
    NSLog(@"%d",currentimage.tag);
}
```

You can get tag at imageClicked button action..

Hope it helps you...

Comment: I try it but not working for me when i write a code on touch event like as
      -(IBAction)imageClicked:(id)sender
       {
       NSLog(@"Buton Tag %d",imageButton.tag);
       }
then it is Print nothing.

Comment: You need to check sender.tag or [sender tag]; NSLog(@"Buton Tag %d",[sender tag]);

Comment: i also try it but it is not print anything.

Comment: I modified the code check it..Above Log will work for sure..!

Comment: i think add a button to subview of MyIamgeView like as i added sublayer in my code then it is work?

Comment: Same Result Display Nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your smallImage variable is being declared outside of that loop? If so, you are just overwriting it each time and setting smallImage.tag=index to the current index, so it will always be the last index in the loop as each time its being overwritten and inserted in your array.

If you want to access UIImageView's within your self.imagesa array, you need to do

```
smallImage = (UIImageView*)self.imagesa[index]
```

This will access the UIImageView at the index. 
Otherwise, if you want to create a new UIImageView each time you would need to do

```
UIImageView* smallImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
```

to replace your existing assignment inside the loop.

Hope this helps.

Comment: when i replace my imageview Declaration smallImage = (UIImageView*)self.imagesa[index] and Set smallImage.tag=index; then it shows error in smallimage.tag=index.Please GIve me Solution for that.

Comment: is smallImage actually an instance of UIImageView? If not, and if its not any other subclass of UIView it crash. What are you actually storing in that array? Is it a UIImage, or a UIImageView? If a UIImage then you need to use the latter method I suggested:
    UIImageView* smallImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];